Parallelization with Do and ParallelSubmit
I have quite a large expression that I need to integrate. My ansatz was to Expand the expression (easiest case results in ~5.5 million terms) and parallelize the integration.
The following dummy code illustrates what I want to do:
list = HoldAll @@ Table[x^i, {i, 100}];
SetSharedVariable[list];
Table[ParallelSubmit[{i}, 
  Do[list[[k]] = Integrate[list[[k]], {x, 0, 1}], {k, 1 + 10 (i - 1), 
    10 i}]], {i, 1, 10}]
WaitAll[%]

However I am concerned if SetSharedVariable will slow me down, as the documentation says:

The unique value of a shared variable is maintained by the master kernel and every access on a parallel subkernel is synchronized through the master kernel.

The reason why I chose ParallelSubmit in the first place because I wanted to avoid any overhead down by communication between kernels.
I could otoh DistributeDefinitions but I do not believe that it fits into memory.
Ideally I would chunk it up before hand and distribute each chunk to its kernel, but I'm lacking the knowledge on how to do this in memory without making a duplicate.

You are concerned ... Have you actually tried it?

Do you really need to use SetSharedVariable? In your sample code,      there is no such need.
